# js if else or - could not get to work

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements

```js
if (kb > 50 && kb < 100 && cts == 6 && kg > 50 && kg < 180 && ay > 3 && ay < 11) {
  $("#ezfc_element-1727-child").val(9);
}
if (kb > 50 && kb < 100 && cts == 6 && kg > 50 && kg < 180 && (ay == 1) || (ay == 2) || (ay == 3) || (ay == 11) || (ay == 12)) {
  $("#ezfc_element-1727-child").val(10);
}
```

As you can see above, I have 2 different conditions, the only difference being "ay" var between 3-11 OR 1-2-3-11-12 ( actually ay refers to a month, so I am trying to differentiate seasons from each other.)

Somehow the first condition works but 2nd one keeps failing.. Any suggestions here? sorry this might be an amateur q which is what i am. did spend lots of time on this one, tried different alternatives but could not get it to work..

Thanks

Comment: Would be nice to have some input data and expected outputs.

Comment: `&&` has higher priority than `||`. If `ay == 2`, the myriad of conditions before it doesn't matter. You probably need to wrap all the `||`-ed conditions into a pair of parentheses. For readability, I would extract the common conditions from the two `if`s into an outer `if` statement and let the inner ones test only the differences.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (kb > 50 && kb < 100 && cts == 6 && kg > 50 && kg < 180 && ay > 3 && 
ay < 11) {
$("#ezfc_element-1727-child").val(9);
}
if ( (kb > 50 && kb < 100 && cts == 6 && kg > 50 && kg < 180 && (ay == 1) )
|| ((ay == 2) || (ay == 3) || (ay == 11) || (ay == 12))) {
 $("#ezfc_element-1727-child").val(10);
```

In the second if you need to put a () braces for end condition and one () for or and now between two you can see whether you want to do || or &&.
as when having multiple && and || associativity matters so having braces is important.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need parantheses around the "or" fields:

```
if (kb > 50 && kb < 100 && cts == 6 && kg > 50 && kg < 180 && ((ay == 1) || (ay == 2) || (ay == 3) || (ay == 11) || (ay == 12))) {
```

but it is just a guess without further informations

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what causes the error but in js AND-Operator takes precedence over the OR-Operator, so you have to set brackets for the same result:

```
if (kb > 50 && kb < 100 && cts == 6 && kg > 50 && kg < 180 && ((ay == 1) || (ay == 2) || (ay == 3) || (ay == 11) || (ay == 12)))
```

What you are doing now ist

```
if ((kb > 50 && kb < 100 && cts == 6 && kg > 50 && kg < 180 && (ay == 1)) || (ay == 2) || (ay == 3) || (ay == 11) || (ay == 12))
```

Answer (score 0):

You just forgot some brackets. 
Use the code below it simplifies Ur version a little bit too.

```
if (kb > 50 && kb < 100 && cts == 6 && kg > 50 && kg < 180 && ((ay>0 && ay<3)||ay==11||ay==12) { $("#ezfc_element-1727-child").val(10);
```